# MySQL Stored Procedure returns Incorrect Value

Tags: mysql, procedure

When I query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM train WHERE agree<=0;
```

It returns 128.

However in my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sample(IN _cla VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
    DECLARE _a INTEGER;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO _a FROM train WHERE _cla<=0;
    SELECT _a;
END
```

$$

and after

```
CALL sample('agree');
```

It returns 200. (Which, by the way, is the total number of rows of table train)

What am I doing wrong?

SOLVED! New code below:

```
DELIMITER \\

CREATE PROCEDURE sample (IN _car VARCHAR(15))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE _a INTEGER;
        SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM train WHERE ', _car, '<=0;');
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END\\
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you are trying to do:

_cla is a varchar(50) **parameter** and you can't use it as if you could concatenate this parameter and form your sql statement.

You can only write dynamic sql statements if you construct them concatenating strings.

Example:

```
DELIMITER \\

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test_dynamic_sql`\\
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test_dynamic_sql` (_min int, _max int)
BEGIN

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM authors WHERE id BETWEEN ', _min, ' AND ', _max);

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

END\\

DELIMITER ;
```

[See here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,27979,30437)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change your SQL statement dynamically?

In this case you have to use PREPARE and EXECUTE.